# Getting JSON data from JSONPlaceholder with Angular

Tags: angularjs, json

It must be very easy, however I cannot find it. **How may I get the JSON** data from http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/ using Angular? I 've tried many combinations...

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
var root = 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';

$http.get(root + '/posts/1')
    .then(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
```

If you want something more sofisticated, you can take a look at [this](https://devdactic.com/improving-rest-with-ngresource/)

Or another [example](http://codepen.io/francves/pen/ZbGyQv)

Comment: get returns Observable, not Promise. Example will not work.